# MVP Pattern with tabbedMDI

Tags: winforms

I have seen some basic samples on WinForms regarding the MVP Pattern.
If I have 5 controls on my winform than i have ONE presenter that takes logic from those 5 controls to forward of the logic to Model or something to that effect.

I have a main shell and on that shell I use Tab Pages in the main content area.
All the Tab Pages and controls that reside on those tabpages are created at runtime.

how many Presenters do I have?

One Presenter

as many Presenters as tabpages?

as many Presenters as controls on individual tabpages?

as many Presenters as total controls?

Answer (score 0):

> "How many presenters?"

See [MVP - How many presenters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444733/mvp-how-many-presenters)